# How to block div on website permanently using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, blocking

There is one website that I like, but with a comment section that super annoys me. I want to block the div that holds the comments permanently, across pages, in Google Chrome.

For a temporary deletion, I can just remove the node using Chrome's Web Developer Tools. But how to remove it forever?

How can I do that? I bet Adblock does not help me, nor do good intentions. Even if I try, I end up skimming through the comments which is not good for my mental health. Hint: It's a sports website with very low-quality comments.

So here is the virtual example:

- SITE: www.sportsrumours.com
- DIV to block: `<div class="comments">All annoying comments go here</div>`
- The DIV is the same on all pages of www.sportsrumours.com

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For this kind of thing, I normally recommend the [Stylus Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) for chrome.

Browse to the site when you have installed the add-on and go to:

Stylus (Icon) > Write Style for > Click on the part of the URL you'd like the div to disappear on.

Use a code similar to the following to hide the div:

```
.comments {display: none !important;}
```

Save (CMD+S), and you should notice the div is now hidden

Comment: FYI: After the scandal following Stylish's data collection practices, the code has been forked, cleaned and re-published as "Stylus". Rejoice!

Comment: Updated URL: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne

Answer (score 14):

You can use Adblock Plus chrome or firefox extension. When enabled, click its extension icon and then click "Block element". Then you can click an element in the page that you want blocked.

Adblock Plus will then block that element each time it is found.

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted. Adblockers have supported blocking elements for a very long time now. So if you can create a rule for it in Stylish, you can block it using Adblock Plus or uBlock Origin, because they support CSS selectors.

Comment: Nice!  Used AdBlock Plus for many years but never noticed that neat feature. Sometimes I get those "duh" moments ;-)

Comment: WOW! Great tip. Thank you. With Adblock Plus you can easily remove any element you wish.

Comment: Much easier than the accepted solution

Comment: This was soo easy! Also sharing @deryb's "duh" moment!  Definitely the best answer :).

Comment: Brave adblocker natively supports this feature as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha/related?hl=en) chrome extension. After installing go to the website, open Stylebot and use the arrow-tool for selecting the `DIV`. Then look for `Layout and visibility` and click on `hide`. The `DIV` will disappear and the change will be persisted. Of course, you can undo that whenever you want.

Comment: Stylebot did not seem to work for me. Stylish recommended in the other anwer works great.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adblock (mentioned by Andrew) this also works with uBlock Origin. I clicked the element picker (eyedropper), selected the element, and then clicked the create button. Poof, gone!